# moment js need help hiding the booked time

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, momentjs

I am working on creating an appointment application using momentjs and I want to add mins or hr to the close-by time for lunchtime. Lunchtime has start and end times in an array.
if you run the below code, when the booked time end it shows the values after next to that: ["10:00 AM",
"11:00 AM",
"2:00 PM"]
When the break time ends at 1, the next value should begin with 1.
I am seeing 2:00 PM instead 1:00 PM. How do I make that happen?

```js
const get24HoursTimeWithInterval = (
  interval = 30,
  startHour = 0,
  endHour = 24,
  timeToPrepareForNextWork = 0,
  bookedTime = [['12: 00 PM', '1:00 PM']],
  lunchTime = ['2:00 PM', '3:00 PM'],
) => {
  let startTime = moment(startHour, 'h:mm A');
  const endTime = moment(endHour, 'h:mm A');

  let times = [];
  while (startTime < endTime) {
    if (!isInBreak(startTime, bookedTime)) {
      times.push(startTime.format('h:mm A'));
    }
    startTime = startTime.add(interval + timeToPrepareForNextWork, 'minutes');
  }
  return times;
};

function isInBreak(slotTime, breakTimes) {
  return breakTimes.some(br => {
return (
  slotTime >= moment(br[0], 'h:mm A') && slotTime <= moment(br[1], 'h:mm A')
);
  });
}
console.log(get24HoursTimeWithInterval(50, 0, 24,10,[['12: 00 PM', '1:00 PM']], []))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Two things: 1. If your booked time consists of pairs of start/end times, your data structure is flawed. (ie should be `[['12:00 PM','1:00 PM'],['1:30 PM', '2:30 PM']]` or something that pairs the start/end times. 2. Your overall solution could be accomplished by generating the intervals and then `.filter()`ing the booked times out of the intervals - hence, leaving only the available time slots.

Comment: the basic question is answered simply by recognizing you have to loop over `bookedTime`, which you are not doing.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks for the suggestion but how do you implement this? Assume you have lunch from 1 - 2 and other data are there as well. How do you suggest using this?

Comment: Given your design, your lunch time would be one of the `bookedTime` pairs. This is required since you have no other provision to block times for any reason.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I made few changes to the code, can you please check the above code and suggest me on what I am asking.